# Magical Record - duplicate records appearing in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, magicalrecord

in my ios application, i am using magical record.. first of all i am retrieving json data from server. Then json data should be stored into magical record. The problem is when i fetch the data from magical record i got data repeatedly.  i want to display magical record data in tableview. if i run the application every time the menu item count incremented.

json response:

App Menu List Item response:

{

Status = Success;

data =

(

{

Text = "Emergency Summary";

},

{

Text = "Problems New";

},

{

Text = "Family History New";

}

my magical record response is:

list items  (entity: AppMenuList; id: 0x7b10fb80  ; data:

{

menuItemName = "Emergency Summary";

list items  (entity: AppMenuList; id: 0x7b10fb90

menuItemName = "Emergency Summary";

list items  (entity: AppMenuList; id: 0x7b10fba0

menuItemName=“Problems New”

i am fetching data from magical record like this:

- (void)parseGetAppMenuListResponse:(NSDictionary *)mediaResponse {

NSArray *dbMenuListArray = [AppMenuList MR_findAll];

NSArray *menuListDetailsArray = [MenuListDetails MR_findAll];

DLog(@"AppMenuList: %@", [AppMenuList MR_findAll]);

DLog(@"MenuListDetails: %@", [MenuListDetails MR_findAll]);

DLog(@"MenuResponse: %@", mediaResponse);

for (int iCount = 0; iCount < [[mediaResponse objectForKey:@"data"] count]; iCount++) {

NSDictionary *menuData = [[mediaResponse objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:iCount];

//Checking for the existence fo records in database and then remove the records

for (AppMenuList *list  in dbMenuListArray) {

if ([list.userID isEqualToString:[[UserDefaults defaultsInstance] getUserId]]) {

[list MR_deleteEntity];

}

NSLog(@"list items %@",list);

}

Answer (score 1):

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // Do your work to be saved here, against the `localContext` instance
    // Everything you do in this block will occur on a background thread
}
```

If what you do is `saveWithBlock` without wait, then multiple request results in multiple saving at almost the same time, so you get duplicate record.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried to do:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
    //Get your data.
}];
```

I am fetching data using [MyEntity MR_findAllWithPredicate:myPredicate].

Hope it will be useful.